# create iframe on https sites

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, https, bookmarklet

I am working on creating a bookmarklet. Basically it gets a piece of javascript code from the server and create a iframe into sites that are from different domain.

It works fine on http sites, but it seems to be blocked by https sites, is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the Javascript code via https:

`https://server.com/file.js`

Just make sure you have a valid SSL certificate on that server.